# jqGrid and JSON array

Tags: json, jqgrid

I would like to use jqGrid to load the following json string. I would like to display the json in a grid with one column for 'id', one column for all the contents of myarray concatenated and one column for 'num'. How do I do this? I have been trying for a while now.

```
{
    "id": 6,
    "urls": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "url": {
                "myarray": [
                    "array1",
                    "array2",
                    "array3",
                    "array4",
                    "array5",
                    "array6"
                ],
                "num": 471
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 4):

All could be not so difficult like it looks like.

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/iphonedevnoob.htm) displays the following grid

[image]

and uses the following code

```
$("#list").jqGrid({
    url: 'iphonedevnoob.json',
    datatype: 'json',
    colModel: [
        { name:'id', width:50, formatter:'int', align:'center' },
        { name:'myarray', width:250, jsonmap:"url.myarray",
          formatter: function (cellvalue) {
              return cellvalue.join(",");
          }
        },
        { name:'num', width: 50, formatter:'int', jsonmap:"url.num", align:'center' }
    ],
    sortname: 'id',
    jsonReader: {
        page: function (obj) { return 1; },
        total: function (obj) { return 1; },
        records: function (obj) { return obj.urls.length; },
        root: 'urls',
        repeatitems: false
    },
    rowNum: 10000,   // no paging
    gridview:true,
    viewrecords: true,
    rownumbers: true,
    height: "100%",
    pager: '#pager'
});
```