# How to display nested Json object in Jqgrid

Tags: php, jquery, json, jqgrid

I'm fairly new to jqgrid
How can I show nested json objects inside a jqgrid as individual fields??
below given is the example  of json object

```
[
 {
"properties":{
 "x":1,
 "y":78093,
 "closeDate":null,
 "
},
"children":[
 {
    "properties":{

       "option":null,
       "type":"",
       "client":"southface",

       "categoryA":[
          "x",
          "w"
       ],
       "facilitiesOther":null,
       "objectId":10,

       "docNo":7897,
       "Provisions":[
          "x",
          "z"
       ],


       "sponsor":"own sponsor",


       "CategoryB":[
          "e",
          "f",
          "g"

       ]

       ]
    },
    "children":null,
    "Type":"test",
    "Id":"10"
 }
  ],
  "objectType":"document",
 "objectId":"89763"
   }
  ]
```

after fair amount of research I found somewhere that it requires modifying the colmodel 
Something towards this issue would be very helpful
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `jsonMap`. You should also look at [jqGrid wiki](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:retrieving_data) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2690657/mapping-json-data-in-jqgrid) specific topic. You can try something like this:

```
colNames:['Children','ID', 'Properties', 'Other','Sponsor'],
colModel: [
    {name:'children',width:100, jsonmap:"children.0", formatter: function (cellvalue) { return cellvalue.children }},
    {name:'objectId',width:100, jsonmap:"children.0", formatter: function (cellvalue) { return cellvalue.objectType }},
    {name:'properties',width:100, jsonmap:"children.0", formatter: function (cellvalue) { return cellvalue.properties.objectId }},
    {name:'other',width:100, jsonmap:"children.0", formatter: function (cellvalue) { return cellvalue.properties.other[0] }},
    {name:'sponsor',width:100, jsonmap:"children.0", formatter: function (cellvalue) { return cellvalue.properties.sponsor }}
    // and so on...
],
```

This is obviously not the best approach because you'll have to know how many records you have on your JSON and do it manually for each one. Actually, I don't know how you could make it automatically, but as I said, if you look out for `jsonMap` on [jqGrid wiki](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aretrieving_data) you'll probably find what you want. Best of luck!

Comment: I tried using that But not working for me
I'm rather confused with what i should be adding as root
Can you be abit more specific with the issue??
because I can't find a solution with the json with this particular format 
      jsonReader : {
            repeatitems: true,
            
            root: "children"
            
           }

Comment: thanks lucasdc 
surprisingly this is the similar approach I'm using right now (before posting the question)
But this approach would give only one set of values
the json I recevie would have multiple values in it
which means the value of 0 in "children.0.properties.client" tend to change 
and I have to do a merging of multiple fields
for which currently I'm using formatter function
formatter: function myFormatter(cellvalue, options, rowObject){ 
return  rowObject.children.0.properties.client +rowObject.children.0.properties. type
}

Comment: and in this case the '0' is not recognized as well which further adds more trouble to me 
I hope I was able to explain the issue :(
Hopes that you could help me

Comment: I couldn't get it straight. What you mean by "would have multiple values in it which means the value of 0 in "children.0.properties.client" tend to change"? It means "properties" will not always be at index 0 of array? Take a look at this and tell me if that helps you

Comment: Below given is the exact json structure I'm talking about 
since its too long I'm adding it as 2 comments
PLease combine it to know the exact json 
[
    {
        "children": [
            {
                "children": null,
                "objectId": "1",
                "objectType": "forms",
                "properties": {
                    "objectId": 1,
                    "other": [
                        null
                    ],
                    "sponsor": null
                }
            },

Comment: {
                "children": null,
                "objectId": "240",
                "objectType": "forms",
                "properties": {
                    "objectId": 240,
                    "other": [
                        null
                    ],
                    "sponsor": null
                }
            },

Comment: {
                "children": null,
                "objectId": "242",
                "objectType": "forms",
                "properties": {
                    "objectId": 242,
                    "other": [
                        null
                    ],
                    "sponsor": null
                }
            },

Comment: {
                "children": null,
                "objectId": "243",
                "objectType": "forms",
                "properties": {
                    "objectId": 243,
                    "other": [
                        null
                    ],
                    "sponsor": "xvy"
                }
            }
        ],
        "objectId": "4102901",
        "objectType": "Matters",
        "properties": {
            "billable": true,
            "clientNumber": "5629",
            "clientFullName": "xyz",
            "shortName": "x"
        }
    }
]

this is the end

Comment: I got it... I cannot help you right now 'cause I'm doing other stuff. I'll try to help you when I have a spare time... Until there you can take a look at [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6631416/jqgrid-and-json-array) and see if that helps you. Best of luck!

Comment: thanks @lucasdc
appreciate that 
I will be looking into this 
If you could post me the solution when you are free from your work it would be super helpful 
In the mean time if I could find the solution I will post it 
thanks again and in advance :)